# What are the privacy implications of sharing or publishing the .onion address of a bitcoin node?

Tags: privacy, full-node, tor

Some tutorials redact the `.onion` address of their nodes for privacy reasons: https://coldcard.com/docs/img/econoalch/Sparrow47.png

What are the attack vectors that they are defending themselves from? Could it be an attempt to avoid inviting eclipse attacks?

https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/263.pdf

What are the risks of sharing the `.onion` address of a self-hosted node with potentially careless people who need a trustworthy node?